# BigQuery - how to register a UDF from the Java Client

Tags: java, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I see from the docs that [UserDefinedFunctionResource](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/bigquery/model/UserDefinedFunctionResource.html) exists, but I can't find the right call to hook it up to a query job.  I'd like to add a resource to `gs` and register it before running a query using the Java API.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add [UserDefinedFunctionResource](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.query.userDefinedFunctionResources) items to your `JobConfigurationQuery` object. Something like this:

```
Job content = new Job();
JobConfiguration cfg = new JobConfiguration();
JobConfigurationQuery jobConfigurationQuery = new JobConfigurationQuery();
UserDefinedFunctionResource userDefinedFunctionResource = new UserDefinedFunctionResource();
userDefinedFunctionResource.setResourceUri("gs://mybucket/udf.js");
jobConfigurationQuery.setUserDefinedFunctionResources(Lists.newArrayList(
    userDefinedFunctionResource
));
cfg.setQuery(jobConfigurationQuery);
content.setConfiguration(cfg);
Bigquery.Jobs.Insert request = bigqueryService.jobs().insert(projectId, content);
Job response = request.execute();
```